# db2_num_rows() returns -1

Tags: php, db2, db2-400

I have a query that uses pagination that worked earlier today, but now is returning a fetch failure. I checked the `db2_num_rows()` and it is giving me -1. When I check the PHP documentation, `db2_num_rows()` should never return a negative value; it should always return a positive value or `false`.

Does anyone have an idea what condition would cause it to return -1? Since `db2_stmt_error()` and `db2_stmt_errorMsg()` both return empty-string, I'm hoping this would help me troubleshoot the root cause of my problem.

Here is a shortened version of my script. The query itself works correctly when I test with the AS400 console using `strsql`.

```
        $minRow = 1;
        $maxRow = 14;
        $sql = 'SELECT * '
            . 'FROM ('
            . 'SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY FETYPE) AS ID, '
            . 'FETYPE, FECNO, FELC, FEID, FEDESC, FEBLEND, FECALC, '
            . 'CAST(FECOST AS VARCHAR(12)) AS FECOST, '
            . 'CAST(FEMARK AS VARCHAR(12)) AS FEMARK, '
            . 'FEMKTP, '
            . 'CAST(FESRNK AS VARCHAR(12)) AS FESRNK, '
            . 'FEBSIZ, FEUDT, FEUTM, '
            . 'FEMDT, FEUSID, FEINS1, FEMIXINS1, FEMIXINS2, FEMIXINS3, '
            . 'FEVER, FEIMDT, FEANIMAL, '
            . 'CAST(FERATE AS VARCHAR(7)) AS FERATE, '
            . 'FETLA1, FETLA2, FETLA3, '
            . 'FETLA4, FETLA5, FETLA6, FETLA7, FETLA8, FETLA9, FETLA10, '
            . 'FESLNO, FESORV, FECMCD, FEMULTI, FEBRILLDT, FEFLUSH, '
            . 'FEFLUSHQTY, '
            . 'CAST(FECFEE AS VARCHAR(12)) AS FECFEE, '
            . 'FECFTP, FEFILL, FEMIXTIME, FEPURPOSE, FEMEDS, '
            . 'FEMEDTXT, FEDIRECT, FEMORTXT '
            . 'FROM UFFRATH ' . $this->whereClause
            . ') AS P '
            . 'WHERE P.ID BETWEEN ? AND ?';
        db2_bind_param($stmt, 1, 'minRow', DB2_PARAM_IN);
        db2_bind_param($stmt, 2, 'maxRow', DB2_PARAM_IN);
        $exec = db2_execute($stmt);

        if ($exec) {
            $this->log('num_rows = '. db2_num_rows($stmt), true); // writes 'num_rows = -1' to the log file
            while ($row = db2_fetch_object($stmt)) { // throws db2_fetch_object(): Fetch Failure
                array_push($data, $this->buildRation($row));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use `db2_num_rows` to determine number of rows found.
You run this function after executing `select`.

PHP [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.db2-num-rows.php) says:

> Returns the number of rows deleted, inserted, or updated by an SQL
>   statement.

It also says:

> To determine the number of rows that will be returned by a SELECT
>   statement, issue SELECT COUNT(*) with the same predicates as your
>   intended SELECT statement and retrieve the value.

**Summary**

I agree, it is weird that PHP documentation says nothing about negative value.
But it says that you can not use this function to determine count of rows found by your `select` query. You mistake is a typical usage error.

Comment: Ok, thanks. After all the other DBMSs I've used over the years, I never fail to be amazed by the stupidity of IBM, such that I cannot retrieve the number of rows returned by a query without having to do a separate query (which introduces the risk of another bug in that COUNT() query).

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that... any "num_rows"-function does not work on IBM-i-db2 (regardless if odbc or native db2).

You have to execute a separate "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ..." statement...

The simplest solution is to wrap the original SQL statement into an `WITH` clause, in your case:

```
list($count) = db2_fetch_array(db2_execute("WITH X AS(".$stmt.") SELECT COUNT(*) FROM X"));
```

So you can reuse your SQL statement...

(as long as it does not have a "FETCH FIRST ? ROWS ONLY"-part... :-) #paging)
It has also a very good performance because you count the rows of a previously executed statement which is is in the cache for sure...

Regards